# Как сделать прозрачным только родительский элемент div

Tags: css, css3, html5, вёрстка, opacity

Есть такой блок:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Серый фон - .item

```
#novelty .item {
  background: #BEBFC3;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5%;
  -moz-border-radius: 5%;
  border-radius: 3%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это правило делает прозрачным все элементы внутри блока .item.
Как сделать чтобы был прозрачным только блок .item, а не элементы внутри него.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надо убрать `opacity: 0.8`, а прозрачность задать через `background: rgba()`.

```css
#novelty .item {
  background: rgba(190, 191, 195, .8);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5%;
  -moz-border-radius: 5%;
  border-radius: 3%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 25px;     
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```